# How to allow different images inside array to link to different url webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to link different images inside the array to different url. The images will be randomised every 2 seconds. However, I would like to make sure that each image has its unique url. I can only link to one url so far.

Need help in this, thanks.

```js
//start with id=0 after 2 seconds
var thisId = 0;

$(function(){
 //prepare Your data array with img urls
 var dataArray=new Array();
 dataArray[0]="cat1.jpg";
 dataArray[1]="cat2.jpg";
 dataArray[2]="cat3.jpg";

 window.setInterval(function(){
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataArray.length);
 
 if (thisId==randomNum){randomNum++;};
 if (randomNum==3){randomNum=0};
 thisId=randomNum;
 
 document.getElementById("thisImg").src = dataArray[randomNum]
 },2000); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Task 2</title>
 
 <!-- calling external js file -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/category/cat" target="_blank"><img id="thisImg" alt="img" src="cat1.jpg" /></a>
 <script src ="Task2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your data an array of objects, that looks like this:

```
dataArray = [
    {
        image: "cat1.jpg"
        url: "link_for_cat_1.html"
    }
    ...
]
```

Then, after randomizing and selecting given element:

```
document.getElementById("thisImg").src = dataArray[randomNum].image
```

And analogically for link

```
document.getElementById("thisLink").href = dataArray[randomNum].url
```